# R filter data by week and year

Tags: r

I am filtering the data frame by week and year such that all the data after the week 3 and year 2022 is filtered out. I want to retain any data before week 3 of 2022. I am using dplyr but am open to any other solution. Below is my code which doesn't work.

```
 mydata <- 
structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B"), year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022), week = c(20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
53, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
53, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
50, 51, 52, 53, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Total = c(22, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 
0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 
0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-180L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), week = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Total = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x60000187f640>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

here is my code

```
 total_type<- mydata %>%
      filter(!(week >= 3 & year >= 2022) %>%
      group_by(Name) %>%
      dplyr::summarise("Average"=round(mean(Total_type)))
```

Here is my Desired output. Notice any data starting from week 3 of 2022 was removed.

```
structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"), year = c(2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022), week = c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 1, 
2, 1, 2), Total = c(22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 
5, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-172L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), week = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Total = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x600001864c80>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your code had a `)` missing in `filter` i.e. `mydata %>%
      filter(!(week >= 3 & year >= 2022))`

Comment: it doesnt filter as desired even with the ")" added.

Comment: ok, I was thinking that it is due to the typo

Comment: with your data and  code i had 180 rows, 8 with (week >= 3 & year >= 2022) and 172 with ! (week >= 3 & year >= 2022)

Comment: Do you want `mydata %>% filter(as.Date(sprintf('%d%d01', year, week), format = '%Y%W%w')  <= as.Date("20220301", "%Y%W%w"))`

Comment: for what its worth, year & week are chr

Comment: @akang It would be great if you can post the expected output as the week can be interpreted in different ways

Answer (score 0):

You could first `arrange` on year and week and after that `filter` based on all `row_number`s below the row `which` has the conditions like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  arrange(year, week) %>%
  filter(row_number() < which(year == 2022 & week == 3))
#> # A tibble: 172 × 4
#>    Type   year  week Total
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A      2020    20    22
#>  2 A      2020    21     0
#>  3 A      2020    22     0
#>  4 A      2020    23     0
#>  5 A      2020    24     0
#>  6 A      2020    25     0
#>  7 A      2020    26     0
#>  8 B      2020    26     0
#>  9 A      2020    27     0
#> 10 B      2020    27     0
#> # … with 162 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This throws an error Input `..1` must be of size 48 or 1, not size 0

Comment: Hi @akang, could you please make sure your are using the filter of dplyr like this `dplyr::filter`?

Comment: same error with dplyr::filter

Comment: And if you replace the `==` with `%in%` in the `filter` in my code above?

Comment: same error when I try mydata %>% 
  arrange(year, week) %>%
  filter(row_number() < which(year %in% 2022 & week %in% 3))

Comment: Could you please try it with a clean environment (restart R), to make sure there are no issues between loaded packages?

Comment: same error after restarting as well.

Answer (score 0):

We could put each filtering condition into separate parenthesis. As you want to retain only observations with weeks `1` and `2` and year `2022`, filtering for those we would have 4 observations left:

```
mydata %>%
   filter(!(week >= 3) & (year >= 2022))

# A tibble: 4 x 4

  Type   year  week Total
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      2022     1     2
2 A      2022     2     0
3 B      2022     1     4
4 B      2022     2     0
```

Taking average of the remaining by each `Type` would give:

```
total_type<- mydata %>%
   filter(!(week >= 3) & (year >= 2022)) %>%
            group_by(Type) %>%
            dplyr::summarise("Average"=round(mean(Total)))
total_type
  Type  Average
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A           1
2 B           2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is filtering out even year 2022 data:
So, do a small change to your code like the below: it should work.

```
 filter((year ==2022 & week <3) | (year<2022))
```